# Using a visual studio project with an Keil application (correct include settings)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arm, resharper, keil

So my company has a big project with quite some files, and i'd like to use Resharper C++ to format the code.

I am still using Keil to upload/debug/build so i don't really want to change too much to the file structure.

not seeing the right include directories
[image]

I also dont need the standard windows c files to show up there.

trying to mess with the properties file, but can't get it to properly behave as i'd like...

properties
[image]
How would i set up the properties in way it actually looks in the right directories?

**EDIT:**
i moved the project to the same location as the  Keil Uvision project and copied its path variables;

```
../Inc;..\Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src;../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc;../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy;../Middlewares/Third_Party/FatFs/src/drivers;../Middlewares/Third_Party/FatFs/src;../Drivers/CMSIS/Include;../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include;..\..\MYA;..\..\..\ARM\ARMCLANG\include;..\..\..\ARM\PACK\Keil\ARM_Compiler\1.1.0\Include
```

created the project without solution file in the same folder as the .uvproject file and copied it's using paths.
still not recognising the right path however.

Comment: Adding include paths to the "Include Directories" property should work, but the project needs to be saved before ReSharper will pick the new property value. Even better, try reopening the project and see if it helps.

Comment: @IgorAkhmetov been there done that, i'm running windows for all my life i've restarted more applications than writing lines of code.